# static object customer | error: 'customer' in 'class HolderClass' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I try to declare the two static objects but I get the error:

> error: 'customer' in 'class HolderClass' does not name a type
>        HolderClass::customer = nullptr;

My code:

```
#ifndef HOLDERCLASS
#define HOLDERCLASS

#include "customer.h"
#include "employee.h"

class Customer;
class Employee;

class HolderClass{

public:
    static Customer* customer;
    static Employee* employee;

};

HolderClass::customer = nullptr;
HolderClass::employee = nullptr;


#endif // HOLDERCLASS
```

Comment: `HolderClass::customer = nullptr;` should be `Customer* HolderClass::customer = nullptr;`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- Your definitions of `static` members lack a type, and
- Your definitions of `static` members are in the header file.

Although one could argue that C++ compiler has enough information to figure out the types of `HolderClass::customer` and `HolderClass::employee`, the syntax of the language requires you to repeat the type anyway.

You should do two things to fix this:

- Remove both definitions from the header. Keeping them there would result in duplicate definition errors on linking
- Add the lines below to the CPP file with implementations of `HolderClass` member functions (or any other CPP file if there is no `HolderClass.cpp` in your design).

Code:

```
Customer* HolderClass::customer = nullptr;
Employee* HolderClass::employee = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only things that can be at file scope are declarations.

But these lines are statements (or expressions), not declarations.

```
HolderClass::customer = nullptr;
HolderClass::employee = nullptr;
```

Definitions are a particular type of declaration.   In this case, what you need is;

```
Customer *HolderClass::customer = nullptr;
Employee *HolderClass::employee = nullptr;
```

which are the definitions (including initialisations) required corresponding to the declarations within the class definition.   These definitions need to appear in a single source file (.cpp), not in a header file.